# How to prove the commutation relations in quantum mechanics?

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics

I'm looking for proof of the following commutation relations,

$
[\hat{n}, \hat{a}^k] = -k a^k, \quad \quad \quad \quad [\hat{n}, \hat{a}^{\dagger k}] = -k \hat{a}^{\dagger k}
$

where $\hat{n}$ is the number operator $\hat{n} = \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}$. Does someone have any idea how to prove them?
Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly is the operator $\hat a$?

Comment: Is $\hat a$ the [annihilation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator)?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes annihilation operator

Comment: Can you show a definition of $\hat{a}^k$?

Comment: Hint: $[p,\cdot]$ behaves like a derivative, i.e. $[p,qr] = [p,q]r + q[p,r]$.

Comment: @md2perpe It is the annihilation operator .

Comment: @achillehui How to deal with the exponent k?

Comment: $[n,a^k] = [n,a]a^{k-1} + a[n,a^{k-1}]$ and apply induction.

Comment: @achillehui Can you please elaborate a little on how you reach the expression? n is the number operator.